# Unsure about Validation of a 3 letter input

Tags: java, validation, variables

```
    double Euro = 1.37;
    double USAD = 1.81;
    double JapYen = 190.00;
    double Zloty = 5.88;

    //First menu choice screen
    if (MenuChoice == 1)
    {
    System.out.println("Which of the following currencies do you wish to exchange into sterling?");
    System.out.println("Euro - EUR");
    System.out.println("USA Dollar - USD");
    System.out.println("Japanese Yen - JPY");
    System.out.println("Polish Zloty - PLN");
    System.out.println("Please enter the three letter currency:   ");
    String CurChoice = keybStr.next();
```

So this is what I've gotten. I'm not sure about the following code which will validate it so that the three letter currency will be entered. Any help? The user input would be stored in the CurChoice variable and used later on in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
String CurChoice = "";
boolean isCorrectCurrency = false;
do {
    CurChoice = keybStr.next();
    isCorrectCurrency = CurChoice.matches("^EUR|USD|JPY|PLN$");
    if (isCorrectCurrency) {
        System.out.println("Hey It matched to proper currency");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Hey It didn't matched to proper currency. Please retry");
    }
} while (!isCorrectCurrency);
```